# Is it possible to get metadata from asset image?

Tags: flutter, google-mlkit

I am implementing `google_mlkit_face_recognition` and the code for obtaining image data from asset folder and processing is as below.

```
Future<File> getImageFileFromAssets(String path) async {
    final byteData = await rootBundle.load('$path');

    final file = File('${(await getTemporaryDirectory()).path}/$path');
    await file.create(recursive: true);
    await file.writeAsBytes(byteData.buffer.asUint8List(byteData.offsetInBytes, byteData.lengthInBytes));

    return file;
  }
  Future<void> processImage() async {
    var imageFilefromAsset = await getImageFileFromAssets('asset/IMG_5105.jpeg');
    var inputImage = InputImage.fromFile(imageFilefromAsset);

    face =  await faceDetector.processImage(inputImage);
    var sizeImage = ImageSizeGetter.getSize(FileInput(imageFilefromAsset));
    print(sizeImage);
    print(imageFilefromAsset);
    print(inputImage.filePath);
    print(inputImage.metadata);
    print(inputImage.type);
    print('**********************************');
    print(face[0].headEulerAngleX);
    print(face[0].headEulerAngleY);
    print(face[0].headEulerAngleZ);

    print('Face Detection Result');
    var facePainter = FaceDetectorPainter(
        face,
        inputImage.metadata!.size,
        inputImage.metadata!.rotation,
        CameraLensDirection.front);
    //String angleX = aX.toString();
    //String angleY = aY.toString();
    //String angleZ = aZ.toString();
    var pictureRecorder = PictureRecorder();
    faceCanvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);

    facePainter.paint(faceCanvas, inputImage.metadata!.size,);

    faceDetectionResult=await pictureRecorder.endRecording();
```

I confirmed that this works and gives me the recognition data.
What I am having difficulty is that I keep failing getting metadata of InputImage, which is null in my case. Since size data and rotation data is required, I tried to make the size data from getSize() like this :

```
Size size = Size(sizeImage.width,sizeImage.height);
```

But this shows me error message like this:

```
The argument type 'Size (where Size is defined in C:\Users\bboyc\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\image_size_getter-2.1.2\lib\src\entity\size.dart)' 
can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Size (where Size is defined in C:\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\geometry.dart)'.
```

When it comes to rotation data, I cannot even guess what to do.

Please tell me what is the problem that my code has.